# Isolating my docker container from the rest of my local network (route add reject not working)

Tags: docker, route

I'm just simply trying to add a route to reject any traffic to other systems on my local network from my docker container, but seems like my `route add` command isn't working and I'm not quite sure why.

The command I'm used to running is `route add -net x.x.x.x/CIDR reject`

[image]

I know I'm missing something very minor here in regards to the command, but cannot figure out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Create an internal network for it.

```
docker network  create --internal isolation
docker run --network isolation $image
```